# Using a loop while in onCreate()

Tags: android

I am trying to use a loop to set up an int[]. Within that int[], I want to have drawables for an Image Gallery used later. 
I wanted the array to be initialized right after onCreate() for this activity, but I read that you cannot use loops within the onCreate() method and I would have to use a thread. I set it up as follows, but it will not work. My app keeps crashing.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {  

    super.onCreate(icicle);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery_demo);

    mySelection = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mySelection);        

    Runnable myRunnable = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

            for(int x = 0; x < 7; x++) {
                test[x] = rand.nextInt(7) + 1; 
            }

            for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
                switch(test[i]) {
                case 1: 
                    test[i] = R.drawable.rs01card;
                    break;
                case 2: 
                    test[i] = R.drawable.rs02card;
                    break;
                case 3: 
                    test[i] = R.drawable.rs03card;
                    break;
                case 4: 
                    test[i] = R.drawable.rs04card;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    test[i] = R.drawable.rs05card;
                    break;
                case 6: 
                    test[i] = R.drawable.rs06card;
                    break;
                case 7: 
                    test[i] = R.drawable.rs07card;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    };

    Thread myThread = new Thread(myRunnable);
    myThread.start();
}
```

Link to my entire code: 
http://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/160l7i/need_help_with_loop_during_oncreate/

Here is the logcat:

```
01-05 12:58:15.274: I/ActivityStack(205): START {act=com.levingston.minisapp.GalleryDemo cmp=com.levingston.minisapp/.GalleryDemo} from pid 7744
01-05 12:58:15.274: V/ActivityStack(205): Prepare open transition: starting ActivityRecord{41b4efe8 com.levingston.minisapp/.GalleryDemo}
01-05 12:58:15.274: V/ActivityStack(205): Prepare open transition: prev=ActivityRecord{41bcd2c0 com.levingston.minisapp/.MainActivity}
01-05 12:58:15.289: D/AndroidRuntime(7744): Shutting down VM
01-05 12:58:15.289: W/dalvikvm(7744): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a811f8)
01-05 12:58:15.289: E/AndroidRuntime(7744): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-05 12:58:15.289: E/AndroidRuntime(7744): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.levingston.minisapp/com.levingston.minisapp.GalleryDemo}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-05 12:58:15.289: E/AndroidRuntime(7744):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2007)
01-05 12:58:15.289: E/AndroidRuntime(7744):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2032)
01-05 12:58:15.289: E/AndroidRuntime(7744):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:126)
01-05 12:58:15.289: E/AndroidRuntime(7744):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1167)
01-05 12:58:15.289: E/AndroidRuntime(7744):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-05 12:58:15.289: E/AndroidRuntime(7744):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-05 12:58:15.289: E/AndroidRuntime(7744):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4487)
01-05 12:58:15.289: E/AndroidRuntime(7744):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-05 12:58:15.289: E/AndroidRuntime(7744):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-05 12:58:15.289: E/AndroidRuntime(7744):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
01-05 12:58:15.289: E/AndroidRuntime(7744):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
01-05 12:58:15.289: E/AndroidRuntime(7744):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-05 12:58:15.289: E/AndroidRuntime(7744): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-05 12:58:15.289: E/AndroidRuntime(7744):     at com.levingston.minisapp.GalleryDemo.onCreate(GalleryDemo.java:53)
01-05 12:58:15.289: E/AndroidRuntime(7744):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4635)
01-05 12:58:15.289: E/AndroidRuntime(7744):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
01-05 12:58:15.289: E/AndroidRuntime(7744):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1971)
01-05 12:58:15.289: E/AndroidRuntime(7744):     ... 11 more
01-05 12:58:15.297: W/ActivityManager(205):   Force finishing activity com.levingston.minisapp/.GalleryDemo
01-05 12:58:15.297: V/ActivityStack(205): Prepare close transition: finishing ActivityRecord{41b4efe8 com.levingston.minisapp/.GalleryDemo}
01-05 12:58:15.305: W/ActivityManager(205):   Force finishing activity com.levingston.minisapp/.MainActivity
```

Comment: Post the stacktrace. it will help in identifying the cause of the crash.

Comment: How would I get that? 
I'm not using an emulator, I am using a physical Kindle Fire HD.

Comment: In Eclipse go to: Window -> Show View -> LogCat (if it's not in the list, click on "Other" and find it there). Then restart your application an watch the LogCat for error logs.

Comment: Thanks for showing me that!
I have the stacktrace now, but It's very lengthy and I'm not sure what I need to grab out of there to be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Rewrite**
There is no reason why you cannot use a loop inside `onCreate()`, but you don't particularly need both of yours. Try this:

```
TextView mySelection;
int[] test = new int[7];

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {  
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery_demo);
    mySelection = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mySelection);        

    for(int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        switch(random.nextInt(7) + 1) {
        case 1: 
            test[i] = R.drawable.rs01card;
            break;
        case 2: 
            test[i] = R.drawable.rs02card;
            break;
        case 3: 
            test[i] = R.drawable.rs03card;
            break;
        case 4: 
            test[i] = R.drawable.rs04card;
            break;
        case 5:
            test[i] = R.drawable.rs05card;
            break;
        case 6: 
            test[i] = R.drawable.rs06card;
            break;
        case 7: 
            test[i] = R.drawable.rs07card;
            break;
        }
    };
}
```

I hope this is closer to what you wanted, I'm sorry I missed what you were trying to do at first...
If you ever expand your list of images consider using [`getIdentifier()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29). It is not the fastest method, but used properly you won't have to type out each `R.drawable.xxx` id. You can simply use:

```
int id = getResources().getIdentifier("rs0" + i + "card", "drawable", getPackageName());
```

Comment: Thank you for your response!

However, I want the test[] array to have the drawable resources that correspond to the random number assigned to it in the loop. 

for example: 

if test[0] = 1, then I want to assign test[0] R.drawable.rs01card. 
if test[0] = 3 though, I want R.drawable.rs03card.

Comment: Hmm... Maybe I should explain the entirety of the app a little more.. 

I have an image gallery that comes up with 7 randomly chosen cards. (the cards are the drawable resources)
The image gallery uses an array that contains the resources. 
I have the following line that sets the Images for the image gallery to the contents of the test array.

private int[] myImageIds = {test[0], test[1], test[2], test[3], test[4], test[5], test[6]};

Comment: I admit I was confused on what you were doing... I only realized my mistake after posting the update. Sorry. Ok, I'll give this one more try. Now that I know what you are trying to do, I might get it right. :)

Comment: Thanks so much Sam! You are super helpful!

Comment: Would posting my entire code be too much? 
It's 175 lines of code. Much of it is commented out as well.

Comment: I modified my code to reflect your answer, but my app is still crashing. 

I'm really not sure what it is. 

Would posting my entire code be too much? It's 136 lines of code. Much of it is commented out as well.

Comment: First post all of the red lines in your LogCat. It will lead me right to the problem. (Highlight the rows the press Ctrl+C, to copy it efficiently.)

Comment: It's too long. Is there any way I can send it to you in a message?

Comment: Simply click ["edit"](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/14174746/edit) to post it in the question.

Comment: `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException   at com.levingston.minisapp.GalleryDemo.onCreate(GalleryDemo.java:53)` What is line 53? Did you ever initialize `random` with `random = new Random()`? (I neglected that in my answer.)

Comment: Yes, random was initialized before onCreate().

Comment: It is a break during the switch. specifically: the break after case 5.

BTW, when I comment out the for loop and the switch, My app doesn't crash, but I do not get my random cards. I've narrowed down the issue to the loop or the switch.

Comment: A `break` cannot throw a NullPointerException... is this the most recent LogCat or one for older code?

Comment: I can run it again. One minute.

It is now throwing the NullPointerException at GalleryDemo.onCreate(GalleryDemo.java:49)
Line 49 is : 
test[i] = R.drawable.rs04card;

I also linked my entire code in my question, it may help you understand what I'm trying to do.

Comment: That makes much more sense, you simply forgot to initialize `test` use: `int test[] = new int[7];` like above. (Also, when you edit a comment Stack Overflow doesn't send me a notification, so I just found your full comment.)

Comment: Wow. I cannot believe it. I didn't initialize it correctly. THANKS SO MUCH. It worked great. 

You were such a huge help Sam. 

:)